# Join on 3 tables in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the below query in my BQ. Basically i have 3 tables (Users, product and Visits), and i am trying to make a join on date.

```
SELECT
  product.Date,
  SUM(product.quantity) AS quantity,
  SUM(users.Users) AS users,
  SUM(visitsdata.Visits) AS visits
FROM (
  SELECT
    product.Date,
    product.product,
    users.date,
    users.Users,
    visitsdata.Visits
  FROM
    [Testdata.productsold] AS product
  JOIN
   [Testdata.userswithpurchase] AS users
  ON
    product.Date=users.date) AS usersproduct
JOIN
  [Testdata.visits] visitsdata
ON
  usersproduct.Date= visitsdata.date
GROUP BY
  product.Date
```

I am not an expert in writing query, but can someone please tell me what is wrong with my query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shooting in the air, but - Try below

```
SELECT
  [Date],
  SUM(quantity) AS quantity,
  SUM(Users) AS users,
  SUM(Visits) AS visits
FROM (
  SELECT
    product.Date AS [Date],
    product.quantity AS quantity,
    users.Users AS Users,
    visitsdata.Visits AS Visits
  FROM [Testdata.productsold] AS product
  JOIN [Testdata.userswithpurchase] AS users
    ON product.Date=users.date
  JOIN [Testdata.visits] visitsdata
    ON product.Date= visitsdata.date
) AS usersproduct
GROUP BY 1
```

Depends on nature of your data  - you can consider LEFT JOINs vs [INNER] JOIN

Comment: i am only getting the accurate number for the visits. Not for quantity and users

Comment: i am glad you have it at least run and producing result  - which was the subject of your question. looks like we addressed it. the issue you still have looks to me completely different and we will not be able to address it in exchanging comments. rather I would recommend to post new question specific to your new issue with respective details. meantime - i feel that your original question is answered. if you feel same way you can consider at least voting on it as certantly it helped you and accept it. all up to you :o) if i will see new question - i will be happy to help you again